# I have a question about type assertion in React events

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was trying to figure out a way to make an event handler for both `onChange` event and `onClick` event. But when using typescript i'm having a hard time figuring that out.

I've tried writing like this `SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>` but if I do that I can't use `event.target.name` or `event.target.value`.

Comment: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events <- exhaustive list of event types

Answer (score 2):

If you provide some code, we can help better. But I try my best based on your description.

Type definitions for both cases:

```
type InputChangeEvent = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
type ButtonClickEvent = React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>;
```

A helper function (ts type guard) to tell them apart:

```
 const isInputChangeEvent = (
    event: InputChangeEvent | ButtonClickEvent
  ): event is InputChangeEvent => {
    return (event as InputChangeEvent).target !== undefined;
  };
```

A general purpose event handler that can handle both cases:

```
const handleEvent = (event: InputChangeEvent | ButtonClickEvent) => {
    if (isInputChangeEvent(event)) {
       console.log("I know this was an input change event!");
    } else {
      console.log("I know this was a click event!");
    }
  };
```